# What's the best way to resize an animated GIF to a specific ratio?

Tags: gif, prototyping, dribbble

I'm looking to resize an animated GIF (of a prototype), to 800x600 to work on Dribbble. Can anyone explain the best way or point me in the direction of good instructions?

Answer (score 2):

The options are many, however the very first option I selected from a Google search for "free GIF editor" returned [a program called ezgif](https://ezgif.com/), an online resource with multiple features.

My test involved uploading a canned GIF from my computer and entering suitable changes. The results were acceptable. One can't expect "spectacular" or "astonishing" considering the constraints of the [GIF format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIF) developed in 1987(!) and limited to 256 colors (per frame) which is not as restrictive as I first thought.

[image: ezgif image]

Comment: That's what I always use, I love it (I think it's great) - they also don't watermark within the gif, which helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could use GIMP(dot)org.  It's free.

Open a GIF in GIMP using *File > Open*

Click *Image > Mode > RGB*

Select the Crop tool (icon looks like a knife), and in the Tool options set the *Fixed Aspect Ratio* option, and type 4:3 in the aspect ratio box underneath.  This will avoid squishing your GIF if it's a different aspect ratio. Make the crop, press <kbd>Return</kbd> to accept the crop.

*Image > Scale Image*, then set the width to 800px, hit *Scale*

*Filters > Animation > Optimise for GIF*

*File > Export As*, choose GIF as the file type, give your file a new name so you don't overwrite the original.

Hit *Export*

When the GIF Export dialog appears, select the "as animation" option. Hit *Export*